# how to solve a very large overdetermined system of linear equations?

Tags: matlab, scipy, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, numerical-methods

I am doing a project about image processing, and I need to solve the following set of equations:

```
Nx+Nz*( z(x+1,y)-z(x,y) )=0  
Ny+Nz*( z(x+1,y)-z(x,y) )=0
```

and equations of the boundary (bottom and right side of the image):

```
Nx+Nz*( z(x,y)-z(x-1,y) )=0  
Ny+Nz*( z(x,y)-z(x,y-1) )=0
```

where Nx,Ny,Nz are the surface normal vectors at the corresponding coordinates and are already determined.  Now the problem is that since (x,y) are the coordinates on an image, which typically has a size of say x=300 and y=200. So there are 300x200=60000 unknowns. I rewrite the equations in the form of Mz=b, where M has a size of 120,000x60000, and both z and b are vectors of length 60000. When I solve it using the function in python scipy.linalg.lstsq, I run into memory errors.
I notice that M is very sparse as it only has two non-zero entries of either 1 or -1 in each row. However, I don't know how I can utilize it to solve the problem. Any ideas how I can solve it more efficiently in matlab or python?

In python I find a library that has the [lsmr](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.lsmr.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.lsmr) method (as mentioned by someone in the comment). Other than using this algorithm to solve the equation Mx=b, I want to know if I need to store M and B in sparse format as well. Now I just create a very large array with all entries zero in the beginning, then I use a  for loop to loop over each pixel and change the corresponding entries to 1 or -1. Then I apply lsmr to solve Mx=b directly. Does it help if I construct the matrix M and b in any one of the [sparse format](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/sparse.html#)? Right now most of the time spent is in solving Mx=b. Construct the array M,b and doing all previous tasks take negligible time compared to solving Mx=b.

thanks

edit: this is the python code I use to generate matrix M and b. They should be 'correct', but not sure if there are other better ways of rewriting the system of linear equations.

```
eq_no = 0
for pix in range(total_pix):
    row, col = y[pix], x[pix]

    if index_array[row,col] >= 0: # confirm (x,y) is inside boundary
        # check x-direction
        if index_array[row,col+1] >= 0: # (x+1,y) is inside boundary
            M[eq_no,pix] = -1
            M[eq_no,pix+1] = 1
            b[eq_no,0] = -normal_array[row,col,0]/normal_array[row,col,2]
            eq_no += 1

        # check y-direction
        next_pix = index_array[row+1,col]
        if next_pix >= 0:
            M[eq_no , pix] = -1
            M[eq_no , next_pix] = 1
            b[eq_no,0] = -normal_array[row,col,1]/normal_array[row,col,2]
            eq_no += 1
```

Comment: This appears to be block tridiagonal.  There are efficient specialty algorithms for such cases.  You can also look at writing it as a quadratic program and using a convex solver.  And then there are a whole bunch of methods for numeric solutions to partial differential equations on a grid.

Comment: problem is that the equations at the boundary makes it not tridiagonal, unless I can think of some other ways of rewriting the equations into matrix form

Comment: If you want to do this in Matlab (as the tag may suggest) this is done just by `z=M\b` , the left matrix division operator. In Matlab, create the matrices using `sparse`.

Comment: Can you post sample Matlab code that generates (example) matrices `M` and `b`? That would help use trying out some ideas.

Comment: Did you try the iterative least-squares solvers (scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr and/or scipy.sparse.linalg.lsmr)?

Comment: I tried the lsmr. Does it help if I store the matrix M and b in sparse format as well? The documentation says compressed sparse row/column matrix are efficient for doing matrix vector product, but what if I  use the lsmr or other built-in algorithms to solve this least square problem?

Comment: M should definitely be stored in sparse format.  You may as well make b dense, since the algorithm is going to be computing residuals b-Mx for various x, and Mx is going to be dense in general.