# how to merge images in intensity plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, linear-algebra, imshow

I am doing a project about image-processing, and I asked about how to solve a very large overdetermined systems of linear equations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30126946/how-to-solve-a-very-large-overdetermined-system-of-linear-equations). Before I can figure out a better way to accomplish the task, I just split the image into four equal parts and solve the systems of equations separately. The result is shown in the attached file.

The image represents the surface height of a pictured object. You can think of the two axes as the x and y axis, and the z-axis is the axis coming out of the screen. I solved the very large systems of equations to get z(x,y), which is displayed in this intensity plot. I have the following questions:

1. The lower left part is not shown because when I solved the equations for that region, the intensity plot calculated is affected by some extreme values. One or two pixels have the intensity (which represents the height) as high as 60, and because of the scaling of the colourbar scale, the rest of the image (which can be seen has height ranging only from -15 to 9) appears largely the same colour. I am still figuring out why those one or two pixels have such abnormal results, but if I do get these abnormal results, how can I eliminate/ignore them so the rest of the image can be seen properly?
2. I am using the imshow() in matplotlib. I also tried using a 3D plot, with the z-axis representing the surface height, but the result is not good. Are there any other visualization tools that can display the results in a nice way (preferably showing it in a 3D way) given that I have obtained z(x,y) for many pairs of (x,y)?
3. The four separate parts are clearly visible. Are there any ways to merge the separate parts together? First, I am thinking of sharing the central column and row. e.g. The top-left region spans from column=0 to 250, and the top-right region spans from column=250 to the right. In this case, values in col=250 will be calculated twice in total, and the values in each region will almost certainly differ from the other one slightly. How to reconcile the two slightly different values together to combine the different regions? Just taking the average of the two, do something related to curve fitting to merge the two regions, or what? Or should I stick to col=0 to 250, then col=251 to rightmost?

thanks

[image: The results I get from merging three images]

Comment: You're much more likely to get good answers if you ask one question at a time. Your first point could probably be addressed by clipping out of range values by passing `vmin=` and `vmax=` to `plt.imshow`. You could also render out-of-range pixels as transparent, either by setting them to NaN or using a masked array. *"I also tried using a 3D plot, with the z-axis representing the surface height, but the result is not good"* - how so? Please be specific.

Comment: Regarding your third point, it's not really clear what you mean by "merge". It seems that you want to somehow normalize the values in the 4 quadrants in the image so that they look "similar". What is your criterion for judging "similarity"? What sort of differences between the quadrants are you expecting, e.g. a differing constant offset, differing multiplicative scaling or something else?

Answer (score 0):

About point 2: you could try hill shading. See the [matplotlib example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/shading_example.html) and/or the [novitsky blog](http://rnovitsky.blogspot.nl/2010/04/using-hillshade-image-as-intensity.html)

Comment: this one should be a comment not answer.-

Comment: @Moj. I disagree. Just because it's short doesn't mean it's not an actual answer. It may not be a complete answer but that hard to give since _Physicist_ asked three questions in one post.